Firebase/Google Analytics for UWP apps
Im developing an react native app for android and UWP(windows). For analytics im currently using app center (microsoft) since they provide sdks for all platforms. App center will be retired next year so im searching for alternatives. Naturally when developing apps I would just use firebase. Firebase provides sdk for all platforms except windows.
I did not really find an alternative to firebase, so the approach im trying is to use firebase but configure the windows app as a web app. This leaves me with the option to use the measurement protocol for screen view tracking. Since I cant use reserved names like firebase_screen I have to switch to custom events for screen tracking e.g. page_view with params e.g. screen_name.
Do you guys see problems with that in terms of analysis in Google Analytics?
Or do you have any other idea to tackle this problem?
Thanks a lot!
